# front/side/top view relative to a particular set object

Tags: objects, 3d-view

I know that the 3D view can be oriented to front/back/side/top/bottom view either relative to global space or to local space of the currently active object.

Is there a way to set a particular object and show front/... view relative to that even if it isn't the active object?

Comment: You can add any view you have as a custom transform orientation in the bottom of the properties panel. Use shift+numpad to find a view that alings properly, the add new transform orientation (you might need to rename, the options appear in tool options side). Then you can select your new transform orientation in the dropdown to use it.

Comment: @kheetor, I know, but how can I set this custom orientation to be used as reference for front/top/... view?